# DateTime.ParseExact Не распознаёт дату

Tags: c#, datetime

Получаю ошибку: String '28 авг 2022' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

```
DateTime DateTimeCreatedOrder = DateTime.ParseExact("28 авг 2022", "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Причём пробовал изначально в тестовом проекте (.NET Framework 4.8) всё работало, точно та же строчка.
В основном (.NET 6.0) выдаёт исключение.

Comment: Потому что в .NET6 другие настройки культур, там сокращения имеют логичную точку в конце (`авг.`). Все это можно посмотреть (как и изменить) в `culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames` и `culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames`, где `culture` - это нужная культура, в вашем случае `var culture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");`. Собственно, у вас 2 варианта: 1. Ставить точку в строке, которую парсите. 2. Менять культуру (например `culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames.Select(x => x.TrimEnd('.')).ToArray();`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это же ответ

Comment: @4per Можете опубликовать

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в .NET6 другие настройки культур, там сокращения имеют логичную точку в конце (авг.).

Все это можно посмотреть (как и изменить) в `culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames` и `culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames`, где `culture` - это нужная культура, в вашем случае var culture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");.

Собственно, у вас два варианта:

1. Ставить точку в строке, которую парсите.
2. Менять культуру (например `culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames.Select(x => x.TrimEnd('.')).ToArray();`).

EvgeniyZ